# Treeview with textboxes outside

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

Currently I'm working on treeview.
Apart from treeview there are 3 textboxes.
By clicking nodes of treeview I need to enable textboxes.
Procedure of that is.

1. If I write text in first text box that should display in treeview's first node's child node
2. By clicking that node second text box should be enabled.
3. That should be same for 3 textboxes that should be enabled.
4. What ever the text that I wrote in textboxes and copied in the node should be saved in database.

Comment: PLEASE REMAP CAPS LOCK TO CTRL OR ANOTHER ***USEFUL*** KEY. THIS IS EVEN [GOOD FOR YOUR HEALTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#Emacs_Pinky).

Comment: Where is your code? Did you try something?

Comment: I dnt know how to do it.

Comment: Did you tried something? If not, believe me: take a C# book for beginners and study before writing an app. Or watch some example you can find around tons of websites... Is this an homework?

Comment: I tried something but its really not working. if (TreeView1.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            txtDesignation.Enabled = true;
            TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = txtDepartment.Text;
        }

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in your treeview nodes are present.
If not my code gives you some error.
All three textboxes OnTextChanged event must reference `textBox_TextChanged` method.

**RESPONSE 1/2/3:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TreeNode first, child01, child02, child03;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeView1.ExpandAll();

        first = treeView1.Nodes[0];
        child01 = first.Nodes[0];
        child02 = first.Nodes[1];
        child03 = first.Nodes[2];
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == textBox1) child01.Text = textBox1.Text;
        else if (sender == textBox2) child02.Text = textBox2.Text;
        else if (sender == textBox3) child03.Text = textBox3.Text;
        // Save text in database here
    }

    private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = (e.Node == child01);
        textBox2.Enabled = (e.Node == child02);
        textBox3.Enabled = (e.Node == child03);
    }
}
```

Comment: this just gives a name to my node, which is entered in the textbox. how do i create a node each time i have to add something in my textbox??

Comment: @user769742: What? Are you sure my code gives a name to a node? Are you joking? In your question you don't ask to add a node evrytime...

Comment: @user769742: code could be written much much better, but I don't think you need it...

Comment: i am not able to get the nodemouseclick event...can u please help me get it.

Comment: @user769742: did you set it on treeview?

Comment: @user769742: believe me. Accept my answer if you think it's good and study, study and study again, a lot, because you're not able to write an application yet IMHO.

Comment: my treeview does not have such an event handler called nodemouseclick......so if u can tell me how u got it?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF? You didn't tell us, so I assumed you're using WinForms...

Comment: im using a web application in asp.net, definitely not WPF.

Comment: @user769742: tags are used to tell us what you're using. Where is ASP.NET tag? I out it for you now, but *use tags correctly*

Comment: @user769742: no, sorry. Anyway after all the code I wrote for you, I'm not going to write more...